# Using gcloud to deploy to a custom domain

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have a Google App Engine application that runs in a custom URL xxx.org. I can deploy an updated version using the graphical GAE Launcher, only by clicking the "Deploy" button. Still, I'm now trying to learn how to use the `gcloud` machinery since the Launcher will no longer work after July 30, 2020. I'm stumped as to how to deploy using the `gcloud` app deploy.

I've tried many things based on hints in the documentation and discussions available on the web, but all I can get is incomprehensible error messages. I'm guessing that I need to modify my app.yaml file. Can someone please give me very explicit instructions on what I need to do? (I should say that I have learned how to run locally using gcloud commands rather than the Launcher, but I can't deploy.)

Comment: Have you had a chance to read through the documentation on deploying apps to GAE found here?  https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/testing-and-deploying-your-app#deploying_a_service_3   ... if something is not working, maybe describe what your thinking is, what you are trying and what you are experiencing.

Comment: Yes, I've read the documentation, and I've searched the web. What I'm looking for is a simple explicit example of what a "gcloud app deploy" statement looks like when the web site is xxx.org, not the default xxx.appspot.com (I may not have remembered the latter url quite right). Not only am I puzzled about the form of this statement, I also don't understand what I must change in my app.yaml file, and whether I'm also required to have in addition another .yaml file.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the app can be deployed with the custom domain it means that the mapping is already been done and the DNS records have been updated. Nonetheless you can find all the important documentation [here].(https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/mapping-custom-domains)

A simple summary using `gcloud` commands to map the custom domain would consist of:

1. Opening Webmaster Central to verify the ownership of your domain (notice that for App Engine using a CNAME record is the preferred option rather than using TXT records):

`gcloud domains verify example.com`

2. Check if the domain is verified with:

`gcloud domains list-user-verified`

4. Delegate ownership to the relevant users or service accounts used by your application with the Webmaster Central page.
5. Create the mapping:

`gcloud app domain-mappings create '*.example.com'`

6. Add the resource records (A, AAAA, CNAME, TXT, etc.) to the DNS configuration of your domain registrar.

After you have tested that you can use your app via the custom domain (in this case `www.example.com`) there is not much to be done regarding the use of `gcloud app deploy`. But notice that if you use wildcards to map subdomains with services at any level you would need to use a [dispatch.yaml](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/reference/dispatch-yaml) file. Which you need to deploy with the `gcloud app deploy dispatch.yaml` command.

Answer (score 0):

If `gcloud` command is new for you, maybe you could consider to follow one of the good tutorials published on [Google Cloud docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/quickstart), with a new simple `demo` app, in a new isolated project, just to validate you're able to deploy using `gcloud app deploy` command.

First, I suggest you to check if `gcloud sdk` is correctly installed and configured. For that, you can follow this procedure :

- [Quickstart for Linux](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/quickstart-linux)
- [Quickstart for Windows](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/quickstart-windows)
- [Quickstart for macOS](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/quickstart-macos)

One important step is `gcloud init` which will initialize your configuration and set your default project, with also your credentials. (authentication).

After that procedure, the command `gcloud config list` should retrieve some environments properties, at least :

```
[core]
account = your@email
project = your-project-id

Your active configuration is: [your-project-id]
```

`your-project-id` is the identifier of your project in GCP. Check `console.cloud.google.com` for more details and an ergonomic UI view.

This is the basis. No need to go further, if it does not work well at this stage.

**Custom domains**

About custom domains, no real link with `gcloud app deploy`. You just have to add mapping, and update DNS records. But it seems this is already done, because your app is already active. 
Follow this [official procedure](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/mapping-custom-domains) (with `gcloud` commands) to add a mapping.

Check Daniel's answer with a good detail of each step you have to follow.

Comment: 1) I can deploy by clicking the "Deploy" button in the graphical Launcher whereas 2) despite reading many documents and trying many things I do not know what gcloud commands to issue to achieve the same effect. Currently when I cd to my app and run gcloud app deploy I get "ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Permissions error fetching application [apps/devbashero]. Please make sure you are using the correct project ID and that you have permission to view applications on the project." I don't know what a "project ID" is, nor what to do with it if I figure out what it is.

Comment: I've just edited my answer. Project-id is the identifier of your project in GCP. It means your environment is not correctly setup. Please follow carefully GCP procedure (link in my answer). Consider also to follow a getting stared tutorial on GCP before to go further.

Comment: But how can one explain that the Launcher "Deploy" button works, if my environment is "not correctly setup"? And I have gone through the tutorial but have failed to find there or in the reference material anything about how to use gcloud app deploy in the case of a custom url.

Comment: Okay, I did get a little farther. I managed to run gcloud app deploy without getting an error message, but it deployed to the "target url" https://devbasherwo.appspot.com instead of to https://devbasherwo.org. So now maybe my question comes down to how to set "target url", which I haven't yet found out how to do.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can't deploy to a 'specific' url. You deploy to a specific project via the command

   gcloud app deploy {path to your app.yaml file} --project={PROJECT_NAME}
2. Separately, you would have mapped your '.appspot.com' address to your custom domain on the App Engine Settings page

Comment: Please don't promote your own content in answers unless it's relevant to the question. If you do that, you'll be considered a spammer.